# Deploying Nuxt.js fully-static website to AWS S3 bucket throws error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'entries')"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nuxt.js

Generating a fully static site from [Nuxt](https://nuxt.com/), by using commands like `nuxt generate` or `npx nuxi generate` or `npm run generate` with `nuxt.config.ts` file defining `target: 'static'` will create a fully static (no server side rendering or server processing required) site in the `.output/public` folder.
Deploying this website to AWS S3 bucket can/should be same as deploying any static website.  It is possible through this process to get the following error

```
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'entries')"
```

when attempting to access the website (regular http). I searched around on the error and found one post about how the `appManifest` can cause this error. Workaround: By adding the following to my `nuxt.config.ts` file

```js
experimental: {
    appManifest: false
  }
```

I was able to get the site working without the error. This seems to be a workaround and temporary fix, and not understanding what is the cause of the error and properly addressing it.  Creating this post so others can quickly find the workaround, and hopefully get a true answer for what is happening.